# How to make a VB.Net Function parameter a strongly-typed property instead of just a String

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, enums

Here is class I reference in this question:

```
Public Class Enums
    Public Enum Subscription As Byte
        Vendor = 1
        FreeTrial = 2
        Standard = 3
        Enterprise = 4
    End Enum
End Class
```

In a VB.NET class I have the following property:

```
Private _optionSelection1 As String                            'added by StackOverflow EDIT 
Public Property OptionSelection() As String
    Get
        Return If(IsNothing(_optionSelection1), String.Empty, _optionSelection1)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _optionSelection1 = value
    End Set
End Property
```

The property gets set from a Request.Form variable as follows:          'added by StackOverflow EDIT

```
    Me.OptionSelection = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form("option_selection1")   'added by StackOverflow EDIT
```

I use this value later in a function:

```
Dim choiceMade As Enums.Subscription = SubscriptionOptionSelected(Me.OptionSelection)
```

I'm thinking the function might be stronger if its parameter could be "stronger" than String:

```
Private Function SubscriptionOptionSelected(ByVal value As String) As Enums.Subscription
Select Case value
    Case "S10"
        Return Enums.Subscription.Standard
    Case "ENT"
        Return Enums.Subscription.Enterprise
End Select
End Function
```

I've tried writing the function like the following but the compiler immediately complains:

```
 Private Function SubscriptionOptionSelected(ByVal value As OptionSelection) As Enums.Subscription
```

Is there a way to use the Property as a type passed to this little function ?

Comment: If Enums.Subscription is an Enum, you can define your property `Public Property OptionSelection() As Enums.Subscription`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking is redundant. OptionSelection is a string and the function you are calling is taking a string as an input. By saying you want the `type` of the parameter to be the `property` you are saying you want a string to be a string.

Now if that string had certain business logic that needed to be applied to it to  be a valid string, then you need to create a class that can contain that business logic:

```
Public Class OptionSelection
    Private _OptionString As String
    Private _validStrings As String() = New String() {"S10", "ENT"}

    Public Sub New(Optional ByVal AnOption As String = "S10")
        If _validStrings.Contains(AnOption) Then
            _OptionString = AnOption
        Else
            Throw New Exception("Value must be in the list of acceptable strings")
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Property OptionSelection() As String
        Get
            Return _OptionString
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            If _validStrings.Contains(value) Then
                _OptionString = value
            Else
                Throw New Exception("Value must be in the list of acceptable strings")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Shared Narrowing Operator CType(ByVal input As String) As OptionSelection
        Return New OptionSelection(input)
    End Operator
End Class
```

Then your property changes to:

```
Private _optionSelection1 As OptionSelection
Public Property OptionSelection() As OptionSelection
    Get
        Return _optionSelection1
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As OptionSelection)
        _optionSelection1 = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Your assignment changes to:

```
Me.OptionSelection = CType(HttpContext.Current.Request.Form("option_selection1"),OptionSelection)
```

And your function is then:

```
Private Function SubscriptionOptionSelected(ByVal value As OptionSelection) As    Enums.Subscription
    Select Case value.OptionSelection
        Case "S10"
            Return Enums.Subscription.Standard
        Case "ENT"
            Return Enums.Subscription.Enterprise
    End Select
End Function
```

What all this code does for you is allow you to enforce what kind of strings are being stored in the `OptionSelection`. You can extend the allowed strings by including them in the array `_validStrings`.

If your application where to try and assign a string that did not exist in the `_validStrings` array, then an exception would be generated. So you get a kind of Business logic type safety.

Comment: you are very welcome. I am just happy it is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Define your property as Enums.Subscription instead of String. An alternative could be to use `Enum.TryParse()` to validate the input for `SubscriptionOptionSelected` and throw an exception if the parsing fails. Here's an example of the property as the enum, although if the sole purpose of `SubscriptionOptionSelected` is to parse a string to an enum value then it isn't really necessary anymore.

```
Private _optionSelection1 As Enums.Subscription
Public Property OptionSelection() As Enums.Subscription
    Get
        Return _optionSelection1
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _optionSelection1 = value
    End Set
End Property

Private Function SubscriptionOptionSelected(ByVal value As Enums.Subscription) As Enums.Subscription
...
End Function
```

Here's an example where you use Enum.TryParse instead...

```
Private Function SubscriptionOptionSelected(ByVal value As String) As Enums.Subscription
    Dim retVal As Enums.Subscription
    If Not System.Enum.TryParse(Of Enums.Subscription)(value, retVal) Then
        '   Deal with invalid value... throw Exception maybe?
    End If
    Return retVal
End Function
```

So in your code (based on your updates) you could change your property to an enum and do this:

```
Me.OptionSelection = Me.SubscriptionOptionSelected(HttpContext.Current.Request.Form("option_selection1"))
```

This assumes that the value of `Form("option_selection1")` will be either the string or numeric equivalent value of your Enum elements. If the form submission values don't match, then I'm afraid you are stuck doing things as they are.

Comment: please see my EDITs in the original post which I added for clarity (I think I may have misled by not including fact that the issue seems to hinge on original input as string and moving toward an enum).

Comment: @JohnAdams I've updated my answer, and having re-read your question I see it's not really an answer to your question `Is there a way to use the Property as a type passed to this little function ?` at all... sorry about that! You can't really pass your property as a type to your function... it's not like Oracle where you can define stored proc parameters with the type of a table column or something. I hope this helps anyway!